# Javascript "Image load" fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a webpage loaded in an Iframe which uses javascript to calculate the height of the webpage document (the document may have images). Right now I wrote the following code to calculate the height after the image loaded:

```
$("#campaignContainer img").bind("load", function() {
                console.log("image load call");
                callPostSize(this.src);             
            })
            .each(function() {           
              if(this.complete) {
                  console.log("Before image load call from complete");
                 /*this.onload= function(){console.log("image load call");
                                          callPostSize(this.src);
                                          };*/
                  $(this).load();
                  console.log("call load from image complete");
              }
```

I noticed that the image load is fired multiple times **in case of one image;**  if the images are not cached it fires 2 times else it fires 3 times.

My question is 
1) why image load is triggered multiple times? Is it a jquery issue or some browser events?
2) Is there a way to stop this?

I tried jquery.one but without success: it does not give the exact height (only the last trigger gives the exact height).

Comment: How many images you have in #campaignContainer?

Comment: Found the issue. There img load calling from some other section which was not evident.

Answer (score 0):

you are using 'img' tag as a selector. So it will fire for  all the images present inside the  'campaignContainer' .

Comment: There is only one image in the sample i am trying out

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The image load was invoked explicitly again from some other part of code which was not evident.